# What is conductive half space in the context of electromagnetics?

Tags: electromagnetism

What is conductive half space in the context of electromagnetism?

I was looking into skin effect, where the author has used half space of a cylindrical conductor. But I am lost on what it means.

Answer (score 1):

Any plane slices space in two half spaces. For some electromagnetism problems it is a convenient simplification to assume that a half space is made of a (usually homogeneous and isotropic) conductive material.

For example, for some geophysical problems, it's useful to model the Earth as a conductive half space.

And another example (with a diagram): in [this article](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00567090#page-1) the study of a loop near a bigger conductor is approached by simplifying the conductor as a conductive half space.

Comment: Indeed, the method of image charges (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges), which greatly simplifies analysis of charge distributions in a conductor, relies on the conductor being modeled as a conductive half-space.